# Javascript gives undefined instead of the ex.message

Tags: javascript

The code below works, only when I type a letter in the `prompt()`, I get undefined message instead of the WrongValue `ex.message` which is in the `catch(ex)`. I have tried a lot of varations but I still dont know what is wrong. How do I do this correctly?

```js
var myList = ["Oranges", "Apples", "Pineapples", "Bananas"];


var getFruit = function(index) {
  if (index > myList.length || index < 0) {
    throw new RangeError("The number you gave doesn't exist in the list, the number must be 0 <= # <= " + myList.length);
  } else {
    return myList[index];
  }

  if (isNaN(index)) {
    throw new WrongValue("Give a number please");
  } else {
    return myList[index];
  }
}

try {
  getFruit(prompt("Which fruit are you looking for"));
} catch (ex) {
  if (ex instanceof RangeError) {
    console.log(ex.message);
  }

  if (ex instanceof WrongValue) {
    console.log(ex.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: check for `isNaN` **first** in `getFruit` put the other if/else inside the else for isNaN test

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do and what error you're getting. Would you please use the "edit" link to say more clearly where you're getting this "undefined error message", etc.?

Comment: Two things jump out at me, though: 1. You'll never execute the second `if/else` block in `getFruit`, because the first `if/else` will either throw an exception or return a value, both of which exit the function. 2. You aren't doing anything at all with the return value of `getFruit`.

Answer (score 0):

check isNaN FIRST ... change getFruit to the following

```
var getFruit = function(index) {
    if(isNaN(index)) {
        throw new WrongValue("Give a number please");
    else if(index > myList.length || index < 0) {
        throw new RangeError("The number you gave doesn't exist in the list, the number must be 0 <= # <= " + myList.length);
    } else {
        return myList[index];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As written now always one of your condition that will be checked since they've `return` and `throw` the both prevent the code from continue to the next instruction, so try to conbine the both condition in one and check the `isNaN()` first, it like:

```
var getFruit = function(index) {
  if (isNaN(index)) {
    throw new WrongValue("Give a number please");
  } else if (index > myList.length || index < 0) {
    throw new RangeError("The number you gave doesn't exist in the list, the number must be 0 <= # <= " + myList.length);
  } else {
    return myList[index];
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.